# Java int value type to Character

Tags: java, arraylist, int, character

I am new to java and and working on a crud calculator that takes input and holds it in an ArrayList to perform the calculations.

I am trying to add two values in an `ArrayList<Character>` and then replace the "+" with the sum.

```
    if(listEqu.contains('+')) {
        while(listEqu.indexOf('+') > -1) {

                int plus = listEqu.indexOf('+');
                int prev = listEqu.get(plus-1);
                int nxt = listEqu.get(plus+1);
                Character sum = (char) (nxt + prev);

                listEqu.set(plus, sum);

                System.out.println(listEqu);

        }
    }
```

When the input is `1+1`, this returns `[1, b, 1]`.
What I want is to return `[1, 2, 1]` .
Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: '1' + '1' is finding '1' on the character code number line and moving to right an equal distance as between there and the origin, to arrive at 'b'. This wasn't what you wanted. (It is very occasionally useful over limited ranges of character codes. In most cases that you see it, a more general algorithm is better.) As @StephenC [explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46010463/2226988), the character codes in question are the UTF-16 encoding of the Unicode character set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things that can be improved with your code :

1. Converting the characters `1` into equivalent integer value:

   ```
   int prev = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(listEqu.get(plus-1)));
   int nxt = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(listEqu.get(plus+1)));
   // Note : int prev = listEqu.get(plus-1) would store an ascii value of `1` to prev value i.e 49
   ```
2. And then converting the sum of those two values into `Character` back to be added to the list using [`Character.forDigit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#forDigit(int,%20int)) as:

   ```
   Character sum = Character.forDigit(nxt+prev,10);
   // Note Character sum = (char) (nxt + prev); is inconvertible
   // and char sum = (char) (nxt + prev); would store character with ascii value 98(49+49) in your case 'b' to sum
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually that adding two characters doesn't do what you expect.

The value of `'1' + '1'` is `'b'`.  If you want the next digit after `'1'` you add the integer `1` to it; i.e. `'1' + 1` is `'2'`.

For a deeper understanding, you need to understand how character data is represented in Java.

Each `char` value in Java is an unsigned 16 bit integer that corresponds to a *code point* (or character code) in the Unicode basic plane.  The first 128 of these code points (0 to 127) correspond to a characters in the old ASCII character set.  In ASCII the codes that represent digits are 48 (for `'0'`) through to 39 (for `'9'`).  And the lowercase letters are 97 (for `'a'`) through to 122 (for `'z'`).

So as you can see, `'1' + '1'` -> `49 + 49` -> `98` -> `'b'`.

(In fact there is a lot more to it than this.  Not all `char` values represent real characters, and some Unicode code-points require two `char` values.  But this is way beyond the scope of your question.)

---

> How could I specify addition of numbers instead of addition of the characters?

You convert the character (digit) to a number, perform the arithmetic, and convert the result back to a character.

Read the javadoc for the `Character` class; e.g. the methods `Character.digit` and `Character.forDigit`.

Note that this only works while the numbers remain in the range 0 through 9.  For a number outside of that range, the character representation consists of *two or more* characters.  For those you should be using `String` rather than `char`.  (A `String` also copes with the 1 digit case too ...)

Answer (score 0):

you should first convert your `prev`and `nxt` to int value and then add them together like follow:

```
if(listEqu.contains('+')) {
    while(listEqu.indexOf('+') > -1) {

            int plus = listEqu.indexOf('+');
            int prev = Integer.parseInt(listEqu.get(plus-1));
            int nxt = Integer.parseInt(listEqu.get(plus+1));
            Character sum = (char) (nxt + prev);

            listEqu.set(plus, sum);

            System.out.println(listEqu);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

nxt and prev are char values. Tey take their value in the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) table, where '1' is 61 and 'b' is 142 (thus, '1' + '1' = 'b')

You need to substract '0' to get the number they represent. ('1' - '0' = 61 - 60 = 1)

The sum is not necessarily writable with one character, so you shouldn't put it back into a char array.

If you want to convert an integer to a string, use Integer.toString(i).

(And, if you want to, get the first character of the string and put it in the array, if that's what you want)

Comment: The value is replaced into the array for use when there are multiple functions present. For example: `[13, +, 12, -, 2]` becomes `[25, -, 2]` and can be further simplified down to `[23]`

Comment: But then, you want a list of String, not a list of Character... Wich can only hold one char per element, not something like 12.

Comment: You make a very valid point. My lack of knowledge in Java is definitely showing here... I have quite a few more fixes to make.

Comment: Hmm, the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) on `char` and `Character` makes no mention of ASCII. Here's the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the characters to their corresponding decimal value before you perform the addition, and then back to a character after. The methods [`Character.digit(char, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit-char-int-) and [`Character.forDigit(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#forDigit-int-int-) can do that (and I would use `char` since that is the type of `prev` and `nxt`). Like,

```
char prev = listEqu.get(plus - 1);
char nxt = listEqu.get(plus + 1);
Character sum = Character.forDigit(Character.digit(nxt, 10) 
        + Character.digit(prev, 10), 10);
```